# How to implement IXunitTestCollectionFactory

Tags: xunit

I can't find any docs on using/implementing `IXunitTestCollectionFactory`.

I have some custom logic on how I want to resolve the existence of some test cases, from rummaging in the xunit source/samples, this seems to be the way to go.

```
public class Foo : IXunitTestCollectionFactory
{
    public Foo(ITestAssembly assembly, IMessageSink messageSink)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ITestCollection Get(ITypeInfo testClass)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

This doesn't ever seem to get run, or at least the exceptions are swallowed and any *real* code I put in there doesn't seem to be run either.

I've tried adding this to the test assembly, but to no avail

```
[assembly: CollectionBehavior("MyAssembly.Foo", "MyAssembly")]
```

Where do I start? Are there any docs on this anywhere?

Comment: Which Xunit version are you using? Where have you put the `CollectionBehavior`? How do you run your tests, with which test runner? I was not able to repro your issue: in a newly created VS2013 class library project with xunit 2.0.0 when I'm debugging a test the brakpoints in my `Foo` class gets correctly hit. You can try to enable the diagnostic messages with `<appSettings>
    <add key="xunit.diagnosticMessages" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>` then you can maybe see some additional info in the Visual Studio's output window's **Tests** tab

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
[assembly: CollectionBehavior("MyAssembly.Foo", "MyAssembly")]
```

Should be this:

```
[assembly: CollectionBehavior("MyNamespace.Foo", "MyAssembly")]
```